# Amazon Route 53 limit of TXT records amount?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Is there a limit to the amount of TXT records AWS can hold? All I can find is a limit in the amount of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit by record type (TXT, CNAME, A, etc..), just a limit on the number of total records in a zone (domain).

From [the FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/):

> Each Amazon Route 53 account is limited to a maximum of 500 hosted zones and 10,000 resource record sets per hosted zone. Complete our request for a higher limit and we will respond to your request within two business days.

So a total of 10,000 TXT records in a zone, minus the number of other records you already have in the zone. And that is a soft limit that can be increased by request.